# A question about the criterion of diagonalizable normal operator on a Hilbert space (perhaps non-separable).

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, diagonalization, normal-operator

This is the excercise 2.11 in Chapter IX of *A Course in Functional Analysis* by John B. Conway:

Suppose $H$ is a Hilbert space,$\,N$ is a bounded normal operator with associated spectral measure $E.$ Let $\sigma(N)$ be the spectrum of $N$ and $\sigma_p(N)$ be the set of all eigenvalues of $N.$
I need to prove that if $\sigma_p(N)$ is Borel measurable, then $N$ is diagonalizable iff $E(\sigma(N)\backslash\sigma_p(N))=0.$

This is easy when $\sigma_p(N)$ is at most countable since $$E(\sigma_p(N))=E(\cup_{\lambda\in\sigma_p(N)}\{\lambda\})=\Sigma_{\lambda\in\sigma_p(N)}E(\{\lambda\}).$$

But I have no idea to dealt with the case $\sigma_p(N)$ is not countable. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $N$ is diagonalizable, then
$$
N=\sum_j\lambda_jE(\{\lambda_j\}),
$$
where the index set might be uncountable. Let $K=\sigma(N)\setminus \sigma_p(N)$, which is measurable by hypothesis. By functional calculus,
$$
E(K)=1_K(N)=\sum_j1_K(\lambda_j)\,E(\{\lambda_j\})=0.
$$
Conversely, if again we write $K=\sigma(N)\setminus\sigma_p(N)$ and $E(K)=0$, we have
$$
N=\int_{\sigma(N)}\lambda\,dE(\lambda)=\int_K+\int_{\sigma_p(N)}=\int_{\sigma_p(N)}\lambda\,dE(\lambda). 
$$
Enumerate $\sigma_p(N)$ as $\{\lambda_j\}$, counting multiplicities (so we allow repetitions but we get that each eigenspace is one-dimensional, and we choose eigenvectors for the same eigenvalue to be pairwise orthogonal). Since  $$NE(\{\lambda_j\})=\lambda_jE(\{\lambda_j\})$$ (again by functional calculus), for a unit eigenvector $v_j$ with $Nv_j=\lambda_jv_j$ we have $E(\{\lambda_j\})v_j=v_j$, which shows that $E(\{\lambda_j\})\ne0$.

From normality we get that $\{v_j\}$ is orthonormal. Let $L$ be the orthogonal complement of $\{v_j\}$. Then $N|_L$ cannot have eigenvalues (all eigenspaces have already been accounted by the $\{v_j\}$) nor it can have non-eigenvalue elements of its spectrum because then $N$ would have them. So $L=0$, and $\{v_j\}$ is an orthonormal basis. Which means that $N$ is diagonalizable.

---

**Edit: some more detail.**

Note that $N^*v_j=\overline{\lambda_j}\,v_j$. This follows from the fact that if $T$ is normal then
$$
\|Tx\|^2=\langle Tx,Tx\rangle=\langle T^*Tx,x\rangle=\langle TT^*x,x\rangle=\langle T^*x,T^*x\rangle=\|T^*x\|^2.
$$

Because $N$ is normal, $L$ is invariant for $N$. Indeed, for any $x\in L$ we have
$$
\langle Nx,v_j\rangle=\langle x,Nv_j\rangle=\lambda_j\langle x,v_j\rangle=0, 
$$
so $Nx\in L$. By the above we also have that $N^*x\in L$. This means that $L$ is reducing for $N$, and this can be expressed by $NP_L=P_LN$ where $P_L$ is the orthogonal projection onto $L$.

Let $\lambda\in\rho(N)$. That is, $N-\lambda I$ is invertible: there exists $S$ with $S(N-\lambda I)=(N-\lambda I)S=I$. Then we have
$$
(P_LS|_L)(N|_L-\lambda I_L)=P_L\big(S(N-\lambda I)\big)|_L=P_LIP_L=P_L|_L=I_L. 
$$
Thus $\sigma(N|_L)\subset \sigma(N)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I still have a question about the 'conversely' part. In the last paragraph you say 'nor it can have non-eigenvalue elements of its spectrum because then N would have them.' Could you please explain this more detailly?

Comment: And I want to confirm that my interpretation of the 'if' part is correct. The key step is to write $Id$ as a limit of the sum (converge in the sense of weak operator topology as a net) of $E( \{ \lambda_ j \} )$, which is  possible since by hypothesis the eigenvectors are dense.  Then both multiply $E(K)$ from right one can show $E(K)$ is $0$. Am I right?

Comment: For your first question, that's typical stuff for normal operators, I added some details. For your second question, I'm not sure what you mean. What part of the argument is the problem?

Comment: Well, ignore my second comment. I think I have already understood. Thank you again.